# What are the prerequisites in learning google app engine for java?

Tags: google-app-engine

i want to try learning GAEJ but i dont know where to start.. do i need to start learning java first? then xml and then proceed to GAEJ? or go straight for GAEJ w/o learning java and xml? any suggestion would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing. You actually don't need to know any Java at all to host an application on GAE. HTML and the Eclipse Plugin are good enough.

If you want to do more complex things, though such as using the [Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) or [User Authentication](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/), then I suggest learning Java. You can try to use GAE as an outlet to learn Java, i.e. *learn them simultaneously*.

Comment: ah.. one more question. do i need to learn xml coz its confusing seeing xml codes and i dont quite understand what it is all about?

Comment: yeah you definitely should. XML should be very easy to pick up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've seen Google's [getting started](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/) documentation yet, but it's got a great DIY tutorial for getting an app up and running.

You are going to be at a bit of a disadvantage if you don't know Java yet, but that's no reason not to dive right in to GAEJ -- just make sure you have the [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) handy to look things up as you go.

Comment: thanks.. im trying to make a project management tool in GAE. I will take you suggestions ill try learning java while learning GAE and also GWT for frontend.. goodluck to me :)